# Existing SpringMVC with JSP Web Application to ReactJs

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-mvc

I have an existing application with Spring MVC with jsp,js as front end.Now i have to do with ReactJs with spring MVC.

How do i change my web application? What is the best solution for this?

I dont find any examples with spring mvc and ReactJs.I have seen multiple examples with spring boot with ReactJs.

Any help would be appropriated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565590/how-to-integrate-reactjs-with-spring-mvc-in-eclipse